# Connect to SQL Server with instance on RDP

Tags: sql-server, remote-desktop

Hello does any one know that setting I need to ON for connect to SQL Server instance on remove PC. 
I have a PC with Windows Datacenter Edition I can connet to this PC by RPD (I know IP) on this machine I have SQL SERVER 2008 and I would like to connect to this SQL from Server from MY Management studio. What Setting on remove DB I need to switch on?
Thanks.

p.s.
Firewall is OFF and Allow remoute connection is on on SQL instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1, SQL server must have enabled remote connections.

2, Between your PC and server must not be restrictive firewall.

3, You need to know also **instance name**

4, You need valid credentials

Take a look at here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/128934/cant-remotely-connect-through-sql-server-management-studio

and here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx